# How to use the AS name in a query WHERE clause?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

given a query like so:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM members 
   WHERE members.network_id = networks.id) AS mem_count
FROM 
  networks
WHERE mem_count > 2
```

With this query, the where clause breaks as it does not know what mem_count is... Why can't I use the as var in the where clause?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

While bernie suggested correct answer to the question, your query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT
  network_id as id,
  count(*)
FROM
  members
GROUP BY
  network_id 
HAVING
  count(*) > 2
```

Which, as an additional bonus, can be faster.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the concept down. You just need the right syntax. You could re-write like this and have the added benefit of making your query ANSI-compliant:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  m.mem_count
FROM 
  networks n 
  JOIN (
    SELECT   m.network_id, 
             COUNT(*) AS mem_count
    FROM     members 
    GROUP BY m.network_id
  ) m 
  ON m.network_id = n.id 
  AND m.mem_count > 2;
```

Comment: This query assumes you need more values from the `networks` table than just `id`. If that is not true use depesz's answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14865010/42346

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as mem_count
   FROM members 
   WHERE members.network_id = networks.id)
FROM 
  networks
WHERE mem_count > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be.

```
Select * From (
SELECT 
  id, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM members 
   WHERE members.network_id = networks.id) AS mem_count
FROM 
  networks)) mem_counts
WHERE mem_count > 2
```

A join as suggested by Bernie would be better though. Basically you confused the parser. You get the same sort of issue with group by or order by when you use AS to alias a column name.